# Read CloudFormation stack API Gateway output in AWS CDK app

Tags: aws-cdk

It is possible to read CloudFormation stack outputs via the CLI like so:

```sh
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name TestStack --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='TestAPIGatewayEndpoint'].OutputValue" --output text
```

How can I do this in a CDK app using the Constructs Library? Specifically, I am trying to get the API Gateway endpoint from a deployed stack and pass that to a web app in another stack.

Answer (score -1):

Better use SSM to store and update endpoints, create an SSM in your CF template, with the value of Api Gateway endpoint, and in other stack use that SSM

Like in your resources

```
ApiEndPointConfig:
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
      Properties:
        Name: /serverless/api-endpoint-config
        Type: String
        Value: !Sub "https://${apiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${apiGatewayStageName}"
```

> Or you can use output parameter to extract api gateway url like

```
Outputs:
  ApiEndPoint:
    Description: "API endpoint"
    Value: !Sub "https://${apiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${apiGatewayStageName}"
```

I think you can't extract directly from CF stack, you have to use output parameter or SSM

Comment: SSM would be a good solution to share the endpoint. But what I am trying to understand is how to _extract_ the API GW endpoint value from the deployed CF stack, via the CDK Construct Library.